# LAST function being ignored when aggregation is applied to dimension column in obiee

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, oracle12c, obiee

There is a "SALDO OUT" measure column that has sum function and last function by calendar applied in its aggregation in BMM. This column comes from a table that daily updates saldos for items so when a user runs an analysis for last month, it applies this LAST function and gets the last saldo values for items for a last day of the month, not just the sum of saldos for all days of the month. Many using BI are familiar with this concept and this has been working with no problem.

However, the Last functions is not applied when we use sum(...) for a dimension column in an analysis. This dimension table is connected to the fact table, but it doesn't really correspond to many to one relationship. For example, for each item in SALDOS fact table , there is an item in Products dimension table joined by item_id, but item_id in Products dim table is not unique so that there might be several records for one item id.

That's why, when we use Count('Products'.'Item Uid') to get the count of items, the 'SALDO OUT' column values are getting summed up for each item_uid. Here are the screenshots :

[image]

The physical query for this is the following (note that names are different from presentation layer, vsego_zadolj_out = saldo_out and item_uid = guar_id, id_item = loan_id)

```
with Sawith0 as
 (select sum(T4134.Vsego_Zadolj_Out) as C1,
         T3703.Name as C2,
         T4458.Currency as C3,
         T57573.Loan_Id as C4,
         T57573.Balance_Acc as C5,
         T57573.Client_Name as C6,
         T5520.Cal_Day as C7,
         T71201.Guar_Id as C8,
         T3718.Name as C9,
         T3512.Namer as C10,
         T3160.Code as C11,
         count(case
                  when T71201.Guar_Type in ('21') then
                   T71201.Sum_Guar_Eqv
                  else
                   0
                end) as C12
    from (Dm_Ln_Cards_v T4458 /* D2718 Ln Cards */
          inner join(((Dm_Calendar_v T5520 /* D03 Calendar */
                      inner
                      join(Ibs_Ln_v_Credit_Type T3703 /* D2707 Ln Credit Type */ inner
                            join(Dm_Filials_v T3160 /* D04 Filials */ inner
                                 join(Dm_Ln_Portfolio_By_Cal_v T57573 /* D2716 Ln Portfolio Dim */
                                      inner join Dm_Ln_Portfolio_By_Cal_v T4134 /* F03 Portfolio By Cal */ on
                                      T4134.Loan_Id = T57573.Loan_Id and
                                      T4134.Report_Day = T57573.Report_Day) on
                                 T3160.Code = T4134.Filial_Code) on T3703.Code = T4134.Ln_Type_Code) on
                      T4134.Report_Day = T5520.Cal_Day) left outer join Ibs_Ln_v_Sector T3718 /* D2709 Ln Sector */
                      on T3718.Code = T4134.Sector_Code_Ln) left outer join s_Oked T3512 /* D19 OKED */ on
                     T3512.Code = T4134.Oked_Code and T3512.Code = T57573.Oked_Code) on
          T3718.Code = T4458.Eco_Sec and T4134.Loan_Id = T4458.Loan_Id and
          T4458.Loan_Id = T57573.Loan_Id and T3160.Code = T4458.Filial_Code and
          T3703.Code = T4458.Loan_Type)
    left outer join Dm_Ibs_Ln_Loan_Guar_v T71201 /* D2740 Ln Loan Guar */
      on T4134.Loan_Id = T71201.Loan_Id
     and T57573.Loan_Id = T71201.Loan_Id
   where (T4134.Loan_Id = 2092469 and T4134.Report_Day = to_date('2021-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
         T4458.Loan_Id = 2092469 and T5520.Cal_Day = to_date('2021-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
         T57573.Loan_Id = 2092469 and T57573.Report_Day = to_date('2021-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
   group by T3160.Code,
            T3512.Namer,
            T3703.Name,
            T3718.Name,
            T4458.Currency,
            T5520.Cal_Day,
            T57573.Balance_Acc,
            T57573.Client_Name,
            T57573.Loan_Id,
            T71201.Guar_Id)
select D1.C1  as C1,
       D1.C2  as C2,
       D1.C3  as C3,
       D1.C4  as C4,
       D1.C5  as C5,
       D1.C6  as C6,
       D1.C7  as C7,
       D1.C8  as C8,
       D1.C9  as C9,
       D1.C10 as C10,
       D1.C11 as C11,
       D1.C12 as C12,
       D1.C13 as C13
  from (select 0      as C1,
               D1.C2  as C2,
               D1.C3  as C3,
               D1.C4  as C4,
               D1.C5  as C5,
               D1.C6  as C6,
               D1.C7  as C7,
               D1.C8  as C8,
               D1.C9  as C9,
               D1.C10 as C10,
               D1.C11 as C11,
               D1.C1  as C12,
               D1.C12 as C13
          from Sawith0 D1
         order by C7, C4, C5, C6, C3, C2, C11, C9, C10, C8) D1
 where Rownum <= 10000000
```

The result in db for this query :

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12 C13
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362403 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362408 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362410 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362416 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362418 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362422 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362919 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
    0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  1362920 Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  1
```

As you can see, Saldo Out item is repeated for each item uid, and I get that this is the natural result of a join. If Item Uid column is removed, saldo out values are summed up.

[image]

The physical query for this one is the following:

```
with Sawith0 as
 (select sum(T4134.Vsego_Zadolj_Out) as C1,
         T3703.Name as C2,
         T4458.Currency as C3,
         T57573.Loan_Id as C4,
         T57573.Balance_Acc as C5,
         T57573.Client_Name as C6,
         T5520.Cal_Day as C7,
         T3718.Name as C8,
         T3512.Namer as C9,
         T3160.Code as C10,
         count(case
                  when T71201.Guar_Type in ('21') then
                   T71201.Sum_Guar_Eqv
                  else
                   0
                end) as C11
    from (Dm_Ln_Cards_v T4458 /* D2718 Ln Cards */
          inner join(((Dm_Calendar_v T5520 /* D03 Calendar */
                      inner
                      join(Ibs_Ln_v_Credit_Type T3703 /* D2707 Ln Credit Type */ inner
                            join(Dm_Filials_v T3160 /* D04 Filials */ inner
                                 join(Dm_Ln_Portfolio_By_Cal_v T57573 /* D2716 Ln Portfolio Dim */
                                      inner join Dm_Ln_Portfolio_By_Cal_v T4134 /* F03 Portfolio By Cal */ on
                                      T4134.Loan_Id = T57573.Loan_Id and
                                      T4134.Report_Day = T57573.Report_Day) on
                                 T3160.Code = T4134.Filial_Code) on T3703.Code = T4134.Ln_Type_Code) on
                      T4134.Report_Day = T5520.Cal_Day) left outer join Ibs_Ln_v_Sector T3718 /* D2709 Ln Sector */
                      on T3718.Code = T4134.Sector_Code_Ln) left outer join s_Oked T3512 /* D19 OKED */ on
                     T3512.Code = T4134.Oked_Code and T3512.Code = T57573.Oked_Code) on
          T3718.Code = T4458.Eco_Sec and T4134.Loan_Id = T4458.Loan_Id and
          T4458.Loan_Id = T57573.Loan_Id and T3160.Code = T4458.Filial_Code and
          T3703.Code = T4458.Loan_Type)
    left outer join Dm_Ibs_Ln_Loan_Guar_v T71201 /* D2740 Ln Loan Guar */
      on T4134.Loan_Id = T71201.Loan_Id
     and T57573.Loan_Id = T71201.Loan_Id
   where (T4134.Loan_Id = 2092469 and T4134.Report_Day = to_date('2021-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
         T4458.Loan_Id = 2092469 and T5520.Cal_Day = to_date('2021-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
         T57573.Loan_Id = 2092469 and T57573.Report_Day = to_date('2021-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
   group by T3160.Code,
            T3512.Namer,
            T3703.Name,
            T3718.Name,
            T4458.Currency,
            T5520.Cal_Day,
            T57573.Balance_Acc,
            T57573.Client_Name,
            T57573.Loan_Id)
select D1.C1  as C1,
       D1.C2  as C2,
       D1.C3  as C3,
       D1.C4  as C4,
       D1.C5  as C5,
       D1.C6  as C6,
       D1.C7  as C7,
       D1.C8  as C8,
       D1.C9  as C9,
       D1.C10 as C10,
       D1.C11 as C11,
       D1.C12 as C12
  from (select 0      as C1,
               D1.C2  as C2,
               D1.C3  as C3,
               D1.C4  as C4,
               D1.C5  as C5,
               D1.C6  as C6,
               D1.C7  as C7,
               D1.C8  as C8,
               D1.C9  as C9,
               D1.C10 as C10,
               D1.C1  as C11,
               D1.C11 as C12
          from Sawith0 D1
         order by C7, C4, C5, C6, C3, C2, C10, C8, C9) D1
 where Rownum <= 10000000
```

Result for this query in db :

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12
0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   34147200000 8
```

What we expect the result to be is this (last function applied) :

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12
0   Кредиты, выданные без открытия кредитной линии  840 2092469 15501   "Fayzulloobod"F/X   06.09.2021  Хлопководство   Выращивание хлопчатника 00116   4268400000  8
```

Data in Fact table 'Dm_Ln_Portfolio_By_Cal_v' is stored for everyday for each item:

```
OPER_DAY    LOAN_ID VSEGO_ZADOLJ_OUT
06.08.2021  2092469 424727200000,00
09.08.2021  2092469 425591600000,00
10.08.2021  2092469 425120000000,00
11.08.2021  2092469 426040000000,00
12.08.2021  2092469 426401200000,00
13.08.2021  2092469 426880000000,00
16.08.2021  2092469 427320000000,00
17.08.2021  2092469 426400000000,00
18.08.2021  2092469 426092400000,00
19.08.2021  2092469 425760000000,00
20.08.2021  2092469 425280000000,00
23.08.2021  2092469 425624000000,00
24.08.2021  2092469 425645600000,00
25.08.2021  2092469 425374000000,00
26.08.2021  2092469 426160400000,00
27.08.2021  2092469 425629600000,00
30.08.2021  2092469 426075600000,00
31.08.2021  2092469 426127200000,00
06.09.2021  2092469 426840000000,00
07.09.2021  2092469 427402800000,00
08.09.2021  2092469 427809200000,00
09.09.2021  2092469 427314400000,00
10.09.2021  2092469 426723600000,00
13.09.2021  2092469 426236400000,00
14.09.2021  2092469 426067600000,00
17.09.2021  2092469 427242400000,00
20.09.2021  2092469 426963200000,00
21.09.2021  2092469 427468000000,00
22.09.2021  2092469 427524000000,00
23.09.2021  2092469 427162000000,00
```

Data in dim table dm_ln_Loan_guar_v stored for each item in the fact table:

```
LOAN_ID GUAR_ID SUM_GUAR_EQV
2092469 1362919 500000000
2092469 1362408 258000000
2092469 1362410 311900000
2092469 1362416 688000000
2092469 1362418 98000000
2092469 1362422 102500000
2092469 1362920 297600000
2092469 1362403 2244000000
```

Is there a way to make this join work or make an analysis use the Last function? Rpd says there should be a bridge table to use many to many relationships, is this the only way because I can't change the source database structure from which all this data come

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, see [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). As for as making the join work - no! at least until you post the query, also as text. Also include table definitions (ddl), the sample data and the expected results for that data. All by updating the question not in a comment.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, @Belayer. .Included in the post physical queries, expected result and sample data. As for screenshots, they were from user interface to make it clear what the end user sees, therefore in the update added queries that were generated for these screenshots